# Push function appears to be overwriting each array element in Angular

Tags: arrays, json, angular

I'm trying to push some conversation messages to an array using the below code:

```
myConversations: IConversation[] = [];
myConversationMessage: IConversationMessages = {
conversationId: 0,
messageId: 0,
messageText: ''
};
myConversationMessages: IConversationMessages[] = [];

this.conversationService.getConversations().subscribe(conversations => {
  this.myConversations = conversations;

  for (let i of this.myConversations) {
    this.myConversationMessage.conversationId = i.conversationId;       
    for (let j of i.messages) {
      this.myConversationMessage.messageId = j.messageId;
      this.myConversationMessage.messageText = j.messageText; 
      this.myConversationMessages.push(this.myConversationMessage);
    }
  }

  console.log(this.myConversationMessages);
});
```

I'm retrieving the Conversations & the Messages within them from a JSON object.
Instead of pushing each message to the *myConversationMessages* array, the following is being outputted in the console:

```
0 
conversationId: 2
messageId:2
messageText: "testing"

1
conversationId: 2
messageId:2
messageText: "testing"

2
conversationId: 2
messageId:2
messageText: "testing"

3
conversationId: 2
messageId:2
messageText: "testing"
```

So the final "conversation" object is overwriting each array element.

Can someone please tell me why my code is doing this? Thanks a lot in advance

P.S. I can upload further code if it will clear up my issue.

Comment: Also, if I put a _console.log(j.messageId + 'j.messageText')_ inside the inner For loop, the correct message details are printed out. I.e. the final object is not repeated, like it is in the array above

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's because JavaScript objects are passed by reference:

```
myConversationMessages: IConversationMessages[] = [];

this.conversationService.getConversations().subscribe(conversations => {
  this.myConversations = conversations;

  for (let i of this.myConversations) {
    this.myConversationMessage.conversationId = i.conversationId;       
    for (let j of i.messages) {
      this.myConversationMessage.messageId = j.messageId;
      this.myConversationMessage.messageText = j.messageText; 
      this.myConversationMessages.push(this.myConversationMessage); // <-= Here you are pushing a reference to the same object in every loop. In every loop you are updating the single object, and the reference in each array spot points to the same object
    }
  }

  console.log(this.myConversationMessages);
});
```

Try this:

```
  for (let i of this.myConversations) {
    for (let j of i.messages) {
      this.myConversationMessages.push({
          conversationId: i.conversationId,
          messageId: j.messageId,
          messageText: j.messageText
      });
    }
  }
```

That will make a new object for each iteration

Comment: Great, this works. Thanks a mill. Only thing, just missing a semi-colon after _j.messageId_ :)

Comment: Nice catch! Updated

Answer (score 0):

It happened because you added reference object to array. In your example you did not add 3 objects to array, you added three reference of one object three times. And change of properties in one of them causes change in all others.

It should be works:

```
for (let i of this.myConversations) {
    this.myConversationMessage.conversationId = i.conversationId;       
    for (let j of i.messages) {
      let item = new IConversationMessages();
      item.messageId = j.messageId;
      item.messageText = j.messageText; 
      this.myConversationMessages.push(item);
    }
  }
```

Comment: Hi, thanks so much for your help. But when I use this code, I get the following error for `let item = new IConversationMessages();`: _'IConversationMessages' only refers to a type, but is being used as a value here._

Comment: I think it is because **IConversationMessages** is an interface. In this case better to use example from @bgraham.